# CssStyleHelper calculateValue fails for a looked up value (-fx-cursor)

Tags: css, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm building an app using JavaFX 8 and whenever I run it, I get a wall of text warning me that a looked up value for the `-fx-cursor` rule of all text input controls could not be resolved:

`Aug 17, 2014 10:16:26 PM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve 'a lookup value' while resolving lookups for '-fx-cursor' from rule '*.text-area *.content' in stylesheet jar:file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss`

I received a similar warning for the `*.text-input` style class and attempted to manually specify the rule in my CSS file, but that did not remove the warning, as shown below:

`Aug 17, 2014 10:16:26 PM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve 'a lookup value' while resolving lookups for '-fx-cursor' from rule '*.text-input' in stylesheet file:/Users/orionf22/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/target/classes/styles/myapp.css`

I saw similar questions online that said it could have something to do with the default CSS file not being loaded prior to some component looking up the value, but the recommended solutions for such questions did not work for me. I have tried explicitly declaring both Caspian and Modena as the stylesheet for the application via `setUserAgentStylesheet()` but that also has not worked.

Comment: Which Java 8 build are you using? Can you provide a minimal complete example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Thanks for getting me to create a minimal example. In doing so, I found a default app with a `TextField` does not display the warning, but if I assign it my CSS file, it will. So I systematically removed rules until I discovered I had a defined color hiding the `text` value for the `fx-cursor` rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake was a subtle error in my CSS file: I had a defined color under the `.root` class called `text`, which hid the existing value of the same name for the `-fx-cursor` rule. Renaming the defined color completely solved my problem.